# Is there a way to show attachment logo in activity history?

Tags: attachment

in Salesforce there will have an attachment logo in emails like this:

[image]

is there a way i can display attachment logo for activity history as well?

[image]

Comment: are you willing to change your pages to VF and use a custom component for Actvity History on every page that allows for activity histories?

Comment: we are not trying to use VF page first atm

Answer (score 0):

App Exchange: https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N3000000B4xkEEAR

If you NEED the attachment logo, try creating a formula field that displays and image, based on the Attachment boolean from the app. ([here](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000007604))